# Display panel on click event of CgridView Column values - Yii FrameWork

Tags: php, yii

I am newbie to yii and am trying to display list of values in a panel after clicking the image button column in CgridView,

[image]

This panel list values should have link to another view. Please provide me any idea to achieve this.

Comment: do you want to show sub table under the current row when clicking on the button?

Comment: No just list values with link to view